# Restriction of finite morphism to open subset, "elementary" proof of weaker version of algebraic Hartogs lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In one of my class's first algebraic geometry homework sheets there was the question:

Let X be a normal affine variety, let $U\subseteq X$ be an open subset such that $\dim(X\setminus U)\leq\dim X-2$. Show that every regular function on $U$ can be continued to a regular function on $X$.

I've almost completed the proof, but I'm still missing a piece, I would like some help with completing it, when I asked the instructor he tried to explain it to me but I just don't get it.

First, we prove it for $X=\mathbb{A}^n$, this is not too hard.
It's enough to show that the restriction homomorphism $\restriction _{U}:\mathcal{O}(X)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(U)$ is surjective.
By the geometric version of the normalization lemma, there is a morphism $\varphi: X\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n}$ such that the induced homomorphism $\varphi^{*}:\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^{n})\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(X)$ defines an integral extension. In particular, $\varphi$ preserves dimension and closed subsets.
Observe $W=\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \varphi (X\setminus U)$ and $V=\varphi^{-1} (W)$, then $V\subseteq U$ so it's sufficient to show that $\restriction _{U}:\mathcal{O}(X)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(V)$ is surjective.
Notice that $\dim\varphi(X\setminus U)\leq\dim\mathbb{A}^{n}-2$, so by the case $\mathbb{A}^{n}$, the restriction map $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^{n})\rightarrow\mathcal{O}(W)$ is an isomorphism.

Now, if one can show that
$(\varphi \restriction _V)^* :\mathcal{O}(W)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(V)$
defines an integral extension, then
$\restriction_V \circ \varphi ^* =(\varphi \restriction _V)^*\circ (\restriction _W)$
also defines integral extension $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^n)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(V)$. Hence $\restriction _V$ also defines an integral extension, and this finishes the proof because we can view $$\mathcal{O}(X)\subseteq \mathcal{O}(U)\subseteq \text{Frac}(\mathcal{O}(X))$$ as subrings and $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is integrally closed.

The question is - How can we prove that it's indeed an integral extension?

When the instructor tried to explain it to me he said something about writing $W=\bigcup _{i=1}^N D(g_i) $ and using "partition of unity" which I didn't understood how but maybe one of you will.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: notice that $W\subseteq\mathbb{A}^n$ and $V\subseteq X$ are **open** subsets, in particular not zero sets of an ideal, their coordinate ring isn't quotient of the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{A}^n$ and $X$.